# asp connection HTTPS and Fiddler show password in WebForms and TexView

Tags: ssl, asp.net-mvc-4, https, fiddler

i have a problem. I've configurated a web in ASP.NET MVC 4 with connections SSL(https). But when i send my credentiales with a simple form, Fiddler 2 show my credentials in text plain...

My web config file:

```
 <authentication mode ="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="20"  protection="All" requireSSL="true"  />
  <!--  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="20"  protection="All"   requireSSL="true" /> -->
</authentication>


<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" lockItem="true"/>
```

and Global file:

```
filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
        filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
```

any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly normal. Fiddler registers as a proxy to your web browser meaning it will see the unencrypted traffic. Nothing to be worried about. If there's a man-in-the-middle listening on the network he will not be able to see this.

Comment: More relevant than the fact that it's a proxy is the fact that for traffic decryption to work, you have to reconfigure the OS to trust Fiddler's root. See the first question here: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp